# init.d script for New Relic plugin for Varnish on Amazon Linux

Tags: plugins, varnish, newrelic, init.d

Documentation of the Varnish plugin for New Relic at https://github.com/varnish/newrelic_varnish_plugin/blob/master/README.md does not beyond an interactive startup: ./newrelic_varnish_plugin

Has anybody succeeded writing an init.d script that would achieve to run the plugin as a daemon on startup?